# what to know value of match(50) and match(0)?

Tags: javascript

I have download pdf of javascript quizes online. got below question in quiz but got stuck with output?

```
const matched = x => ({
    on: () => matched(x),
    otherwise: () => x,
})
const match = x => ({
    on: (pred, fn) => (pred(x) ? matched(fn(x)) : match(x)),
    otherwise: fn => fn(x),
})
match(x)
    .on(x => x < 0, () => 0)
    .on(x => x >= 0 && x <= 1, () => 1)
    .otherwise(x => x * 10)
```

What’s the value of match(50) & match(0) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can debug the statements step by step and eventually we will get the expected result. But there is an easy way if we look deep into the logic:

- `matched` will keep the input `x` no matter how many times we call `on`, and then yields the input on `otherwise` as the final result.
- `match` will check the `pred` condition first

  - if it evaluates to `true`, then it calculates a result based on the `fn` we passed to `on`, keep the result in a `matched` object
  - if the `pred` evaluates to `false`, then it doesn't match, hence it returns the same `match` object, awaits the next match. If there is no match in the last, the function we passed to `otherwise` will be called to get the final result.

Based on what we have above, we noticed that a `match` object will evaluate the condition on every `on` event, keep the first `matched` result, and finally return it on an `otherwise` event.

So we have a few `pred` conditions

1. `x => x < 0`
2. `x => x >= 0 && x <= 1`

`50` doesn't match any of this so it will invoke the final `fn` we passed to `otherwise`, which is `x => x*10` hence we have `500`.

`1` matches the second condition so in the second iteration it yields `1` because we passed `() => 1` as `fn`, the result was kept in a `matched` object until we retrieve it with `otherwise`, hence we have `1`.

This is an example of those kinds of JavaScript functions that smells smart but we should never do in production.